# IOS connecting to BLE devices EXC_BREAKPOINT at didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been working on the implementation of bluetooth module to connect with the BLE devices. When it comes to the execution, it shows that here has the

EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT.. that )

and exits suddenly when the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath is invoked by clicking the table cell.

Are there any other alternatives in order to connect with the BLE devices or loading more information of the BLE devices. It seems that if the BLE device has been already paired with the other iOS devices, we cannot initiate thew pairing and connection. Is that true ?

The stopping line is

```
    _currentperipheral =    [_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The below is my code

```
#import "BluetoothTableViewController.h"
#import "BTSentCommandViewController.h"
#import "BTDevice.h";


@interface BluetoothTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation BluetoothTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pendingInit = YES;

    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    _currentperipheral=[[CBPeripheral alloc]init];
    _founddevice=FALSE;
    _foundPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _connectedServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [_centralManager stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if( [_centralManager isEqual:nil ] ){
        NSLog(@"Bluetooth central manager is nil , cannot instantiate");
    }else{
        if( _centralManager.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
        {
            NSLog(@"Bluetooth not turned on");
        }else{

            _currentperipheral =    [_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [_centralManager connectPeripheral: _currentperipheral options:nil]; // it's wrong
            BTSentCommandViewController* sliderVC= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BTSentCommandViewController"];

            sliderVC.centralManager=_centralManager;
            sliderVC.periperhal= _currentperipheral;
            // sliderVC.delegate = self;
            [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return  1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_foundPeripherals count];
}



- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    // You should test all scenarios
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // Scan for devices

        [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        NSLog(@"Scanning started");
    }
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    //  NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

    if ( ![_foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {

        //  BTDevice *myDevice=[[BTDevice alloc] init];
        // [myDevice setName: peripheral.name];
        //  NSString * macAddress =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , peripheral.identifier];
        //  [myDevice setMacAddress: macAddress];

        [_foundPeripherals addObject: peripheral ] ;

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        // And connect
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect");
    [self cleanup];
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"Connected");

    [_centralManager stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");

    // [_data setLength:0];

    peripheral.delegate = self;

    [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]] forService:service];
    }
    // Discover other characteristics
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
        return;
    }

    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Have we got everything we need?
    if ([stringFromData isEqualToString:@"EOM"]) {

        //[_textview setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [peripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];

        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }

    //[_data appendData:characteristic.value];
}


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

    if (![characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
        return;
    }

    if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
        NSLog(@"Notification began on %@", characteristic);
    } else {
        // Notification has stopped
        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    _foundPeripherals = nil;

    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
}

- (void)cleanup {

    // See if we are subscribed to a characteristic on the peripheral
    if (_currentperipheral.services != nil) {
        for (CBService *service in _currentperipheral.services) {
            if (service.characteristics != nil) {
                for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
                    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
                        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
                            [_currentperipheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:_currentperipheral];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reuseIdentifier";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"] ;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }

    CBPeripheral *peripheral=[_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * macAddress =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@" ,peripheral.name , peripheral.UUID  ];

    cell.textLabel.text = macAddress;
    // Configure the cell...
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: A bad access exception is nothing (specifically) to do with Core Bluetooth.  It means that you are accessing memory that you shouldn't be - either a null or invalid pointer.  An exception breakpoint, or single-stepping through your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should help you isolate the line that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this because your app is creating a CBPeripheral. All CBPeripherals should be created by the CoreBluetooth framework.

On your CBCentralManager use the following methods to get a CBPeripheral:

- `- (void)scanForPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs options:(NSDictionary *)options`

On your delegate, this will call `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:` and pass you a reference to a CBPeripheral.

- `- (NSArray *)retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs`
- `- (NSArray *)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers`

These two return arrays of CBPeripherals (either currently connected, or previously connected).

Never create a CBPeripheral using `[[CBPeripheral alloc] init]` or `[CBPeripheral new]` or you'll get this error when you release the CBPeripheral.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit of **"precuations"** for *unknown exception* ...modified the code ..Try this...Its self explanatory

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(_centralManager){
        if( _centralManager.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
        {
            NSLog(@"Bluetooth not turned on");
        }
        else
        {
            if ([_foundPeripherals count]> indexpath.row) {
                _currentperipheral = [_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [_centralManager connectPeripheral: _currentperipheral options:nil]; // it's wrong
                BTSentCommandViewController* sliderVC= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BTSentCommandViewController"];
                sliderVC.centralManager=_centralManager;
                sliderVC.periperhal= _currentperipheral;
                // sliderVC.delegate = self;
                [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Value doesn't exist in array");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Bluetooth central manager is nil , cannot instantiate");
    }
}
```

Comment: I swear all variables are not null but somehow it _centralManager is released

Comment: And the error still begins at                _currentperipheral = [_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: @RajuGujarati make sure the array has value

Comment: still failed , Lthiu. I have seen that [CBPeripheral release] above the highlighted lines in the debug console

Comment: _foundPeripherals  : make it strong reference

Comment: And it works after removing retain at currentperipheral